# Badge-pill and h2 horizontal alignment

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am learning Bootstrap. I wanted to create a large heading followed by 3 *small* horizontally centered badge-pills. I found 2 problems:

1-The badge-pills stacked together without any spaces, this may be due to the push-right. I had to insert a "blank badge-pill" to create the space (maybe not the best idea).

2-The header and the badge-pills are not aligned horizontally well, I have no fix for this one, so please help.

Edit: What I want may look very much like a Navbar, I assume a simpler way exists.

Code:

```
<div class="container border p-3">
   <span class="h2 align-middle">Heading 1</span>

      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark align-middle p-2 pull-right">Top</span>  
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-light pull-right">&nbsp</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark align-middle p-2 pull-right">Prev.</span> 
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-light pull-right">&nbsp</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark align-middle p-2 pull-right">Next</span> 

    </div>
```

fiddle:[code](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/aq9Laaew/256551/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the classes `d-flex justify-content-between` to the div:

```
<div class="container border p-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion somewhat solves the problem between the badges, however, it stretches each badge vertically and it centers all the pills in space between the header and the container, which I don't want. I want the badges to be right justified with space between them. Thanks again.